# Is there a bash command to display bash shortcuts?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, readline

Given a command like:

```
bash --shortcuts
```

I want to display a list of shortcuts, like on this page:

http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/bash-shortcuts-for-maximum-productivity/

Does it exist?

Comment: These commands are related to `readline` not bash.

Answer (score 3):

Those are almost all readline keyboard shortcuts. You can see all of those with

`bind -p`

Comment: Note that you may have to google some of the strangely named shortcuts, and need to know that `\e` means Esc (or Alt or Meta depending on your system) and `\C` means Control

Answer (score 1):

You mean like `help`?

And the manpage is quite informative, stuff like string substitution can be quite handy.